# HTML to NSAttributeString issue with &

Tags: html, ios, objective-c, nsattributedstring

i´m using this git project: https://gist.github.com/xslim/851018

I want to show font styles on my textview, like bold, italic, underline....

and i call it with:

```
self.dataTextView.attributedText = [[NSAttributedString alloc]initWithHTML:item.text];
```

"item.text" come from a webserver by use of an api (JSON), it includes html entities for special characters!

Everythings works fine, like bold, italic..... except of the tags: & < >

**EDIT:**

For Example with & :

**My Input from the webserver (item.text):**

```
@"I play football &amp; <b>tennis</b>"
```

**The displayed Result on my Iphone:**

I play football &amp amp; **tennis**.

The expected result on my iphone should be:

```
I play football & tennis
```

It seems that "initWithHTML" brokes my html encoding, and i dont know why....

I can´t figure out the reason why its not working?

Comment: your question is not clear. Can you please explain little bit more what you want to achieve??

Comment: you need to clear the html characters in your text right?

Comment: I want to display the encoded Text properly :)

Comment: Does item.text come from XML?

Comment: No from a webserver by use of an API :)

Comment: What is the format of API response? XML?

Comment: No its not XML, its JSON :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this line on your code
here data will be `NSData`:-

```
NSString *readableData = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Also as you wanted i have done some changes on your code:-

```
NSString *str=@"I play football &amp; <b>tennis</b>";
NSString *str1=[str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"amp" withString:@""];
NSLog(@"str1=%@",str1);
```

Output:-- `I play football &; <b>tennis</b>`

Comment: i tried it like this: NSData* data = [item.text dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
            
              NSString *readableData = [[NSString alloc] initWithData: data encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
            
            self.dataTextView.attributedText = [[NSAttributedString alloc]initWithHTML:readableData];

Comment: What is exactly the issue?

Comment: Nothings changed with this Code, the Result on my iphone is still "&ampamp;" and not only "&" what i would like to achieve :)

Comment: oh but then you need to replace your string using this method  stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString

Comment: Can you paste here your exact input string and output string

Comment: Input String (item.text) from webserver: @"I play football &amp; <b>tennis</b>" and the output string (displayed on my iphone: I play football &ampamp; **tennis**.